# Unable to send keys to inactive window using win32api.PostMessage

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, win32gui, win32con

I am using the below code to send keys to an inactive window using python on windows:

```
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
import time
import win32com.client

def send_key(hwnd, key):
    win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, key, 0)
    time.sleep(1)
    win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, key, 0)
   
def send_key_comb(hwnd, key1, key2):
     win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, key1, 0)
     time.sleep(1)
     win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, key2, 0)
     time.sleep(1)
     win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, key1, 0)
     time.sleep(1)
     win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, key2, 0)
     time.sleep(1)
     
    
def get_window_handle():
    hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "MyApp - V2.2")
    #
    # Notepad example - working
    #
    # hwndMain = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "*Untitled - Notepad")
    #
    return hwndMain
     
def send_str(hwnd, strng):
    for c in strng:
        send_key(hwnd, ord(c))
       
def send_tabs(hwnd, n):
    for i in range(n):
        send_key(hwnd, win32con.VK_TAB)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    hwnd = get_window_handle()
    send_str(hwnd, "abcd")
    #
    # Tried the below also, but not working
    #
    # child =  win32gui.GetWindow(hwnd, win32con.GW_CHILD)
    # send_str(child, "abcd")
```

This script is sending "11223344" to notepad application, but it is not sending keys to my specific application window

I also noticed that the script is able to send tabs to the specific application window, but it fails while sending the characters

Not sure what could be wrong. Any pointers would be very helpful

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32), provided by `pywinauto` with `backend="uia"`. No reason to avoid applying the solution.

Comment: Thousands of questions have been posted here asking this question

Comment: Thanks all of you. Will try UI Automation

Comment: Is there a python module for UI Automation?

Comment: The module name is *literally* spelled out in my first comment. Anyway, here's a link to the [documentation](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks @IInspectable